# Bash script to compile a program and run it works in the terminal but not as a bash script

Tags: bash, gcc, g++

I have a simple series of commands that need to be executed as root:

```
#/bin/bash
g++ -O3 -ffast-math -msse4 -c *.c *.cpp  -lGL -lglfw -m64 -Wno-undef -fPIC
rm main.o
g++ -O3 -ffast-math -msse4 -shared -o GeklminRender.so *.o -m64 -Wno-undef -lGL -lglfw
#In your root window:
cp /home/gek/Programming/GeklminRender-master/THEVERSION/GeklminRender.so /usr/lib/GeklminRender.so
g++ -O3 -ffast-math -msse4 -lGL -lglfw -m64 -Wno-undef -Wall -L. -l:GeklminRender.so -o prog2.bin main.cpp
#./prog2.bin
```

When I run these commands individually by copy-pasting them into LXTerminal, it runs completely fine.

When I run the SH file it prints out this series of errors (Note: It's being executed in a root terminal by typing in ./Compiler_Call.sh)

```
’; did you mean ‘-fPIC’?
rm: cannot remove 'main.o'$'\r': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cp: cannot stat '/home/gek/Programming/GeklminRender-master/THEVERSION/GeklminRender.so': No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
```

Now, maybe I'm just missing something (I'm a life-long windows user, where batch scripts run always 100% of the time whether or not you typed it into the terminal or ran it in a .bat file) but I don't understand why things I type into the terminal don't work from a .sh file. My shell is indeed `bash`!

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `'main.o'$'\r'` appears in your output is very telling. It suggests that there is an extra carriage return character in your script at the end of the line `rm main.o`. That character is invisible to you, but not to bash, so even though it looks to you as if you wrote a command to remove the file `main.o`, bash sees a command to remove the file `main.o\r` (where `\r` stands for the invisible carriage return character), and of course there is no file by that name.

If there are carriage returns at the end of your other lines, that would probably also explain the other error messages you're seeing. For example, `’; did you mean ‘-fPIC’?` probably comes from GCC trying to display a message something like this

```
invalid option ‘-fPIC\r’; did you mean ‘-fPIC’?
```

but because GCC actually moves the display cursor back to the beginning of the line when the `\r` comes up, the second half of the message overwrites the first half. And `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw` is probably actually `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw\r`, where the carriage return at the end is invisible.

This would happen if you wrote this script file in a text editor that uses Windows-style line endings. To make it run in bash, you'll have to convert the line endings to Unix-style, which means removing all the carriage return characters. How you do this depends on what tools you have available.

Answer (score -1):

I FOUND THE ANSWER!!!
I was using Microsoft DOS line endings

Comment: That's what @David's answer said. You may want to accept the answer, then.